# Running javascript method from local file, very slow in some iOS devices. iPad mini, iPad 3

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, webview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to call javascript method from a xamarin ios project. JS files are in the project folder.

At first I have tried to use UIWebView. It was working in simulators and most of the devices. I did something like this...

First I load the html file containing js methods.And then i call js method.

```
webview.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (address)));
webview.EvaluateJavascript (String.Format ("Client.authenticateUser('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", email, password, onSuccess, onFailure));
```

It was ok in all simulators. However, when I tested in my ipad mini, the response from the js methods came after a big delay (nearly 2 min).

Then i found that WKWebview is better than UIWebview and i tried to use that also. But same result, js methods are giving response with great delay in ipad mini and ipad 3.

Here is my code using WKWebview

```
loginBtn.TouchUpInside += delegate {

    var userController = new WKUserContentController ();
    userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "myapp");
    var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration {
        UserContentController = userController
    };

    wkwebview = new WKWebView (new CGRect (0, 0, 0, 0), config);
    wkwebview.NavigationDelegate = this;


    string index = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath,"www/main.html");
    string webAppFolder = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath, "www");
    wkwebview.LoadFileUrl (new NSUrl ("file://" + index), new NSUrl("file://"+ webAppFolder, true));
};


[Export ("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
public void DidFinishNavigation (WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{
  string email = emailField.Value;
  string password = passwordField.Value;

  webView.EvaluateJavaScript (new NSString (String.Format ("Client.newAuthenticateUser('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", email, password, "onSuccess", "onFailure")), (result, error) => {

  });
}

public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
{
   var msg = message.Body.ToString ();
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (msg);
}
```

What may be the solution for this? Is there anything I am missing to implement this? Or is it for device lower configurations? Please help.

Comment: `UIWebView` JavaScript is known to be slow. Consider it like expected behavior.